# How do I call a jquery function on submitting a form?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form which is given below :

```
 <form method="post" id="contactForm" action="">
                <fieldset class="contactFieldset">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <label for="contactName" class="leftLabel">*Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="contactName" id="contactName" class="contactInput required" value="" />

                        </li>
                        <p></p>
                        <li>
                            <label for="email" class="leftLabel">*Email:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="contactInput email required" value="" />
                        </li>
                      <span class="simple-success">I'll be in  touch soon</span>
                        <li>
                            <label for="subject" class="leftLabel">*Subject:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="contactInput required" value="" />
                        </li>
                        <p></p>
                        <li>
                            <label for="message" class="leftLabel">Message:</label>
                            <textarea rows="10" cols="40" id="message" name="message" class="contactTextarea required"></textarea>

                        </li>
                       <p></p>
                        <li>


                            <input type="image" src="images/submitbutton.png" alt="Submit button" name="submit_button" class="submit_button" id="submit_button">

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

I am trying to extract the data from this form via jquery so that I can pass it on to the php file and send an email but the jquery function is not being called on clicking the button.The code is given below:

```
    $(function() {
  $('.error').hide();
  $('.simple-sucess').hide();

  $(".submit_button").click(function() {





        /*get the email value*/

        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var name = $("input#contactName").val();
        var subject = $("input#subject").val();
        var message=$("input#message").val();
    //  alert("email"+email);

/* Check if the email is good or bad */

var goodEmail = email.match(/\b(^(\S+@).+((\.com)|(\.net)|(\.edu)|(\.mil)|(\.gov)|(\.org)|(\.info)|(\.sex)|(\.biz)|(\.aero)|(\.coop)|(\.museum)|(\.name)|(\.pro)|(\.arpa)|(\.asia)|(\.cat)|(\.int)|(\.jobs)|(\.tel)|(\.travel)|(\.xxx)|(\..{2,2}))$)\b/gi);
    apos=email.indexOf("@");dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");lastpos=email.length-1;
    var badEmail    = (apos<1 || dotpos-apos<2 || lastpos-dotpos<2);

/*If the email is bad ,display the error message*/

if (email=="" || !goodEmail || badEmail) {

        $("email").focus();
      return false;
    }


        var dataString = 'email='+ email + '\n Name='+ name+ '\n Subject='+ subject+ '\n message='+ message;
        alert (dataString);

        $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "mai.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function() {
        $('.simple-sucess').fadeIn(100).show();
        $('.contact_form').fadeOut(100).hide();
        $('.simple_error').fadeOut(100).hide();


      }
     });
    return false;
    });
});
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should use a `document.ready` block and don't use `submit-button` click; instead use `$.submit()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("your form selector here").submit(function() {


    // do the extra stuff here
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
      url: "mail.php",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function() {
        $('.simple-sucess').fadeIn(100).show();
        $('.contact_form').fadeOut(100).hide();
        $('.simple_error').fadeOut(100).hide();

       }
    })

  })
})
```

Take a look at the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/), whic has methods like `ajaxSubmit()` to reduce your work.

Answer (score 8):

Put your javascript code in

```
$(document).ready({

   $('#contactForm').submit(function() {

      //Do stuff here

   }); 

});
```

Answer (score 7):

Use onsubmit for checking of a form is submitted:

```
$('#contactForm').on('submit', function() {
  alert('You submitted the form!');
});
```

Comment: does it fire when the submit happens or after the submit is done?

Answer (score 0):

First off, try to debug your code - Chrome has a neat console built-in (Ctrl + Shift + J) and Firefox has the awesome FireBug addon. You can then use `console.log("Message");` anywhere to check if the function has reached that area.

Is that `alert("email" + email)` working?

Be sure to wrap everything in `$().ready({ /* your code */ });`. Right now your code is probably being run *before* the rest of the document is loaded and, thus, when it tries to find the button to bind the event to, it fails and the event doesn't get tied to anything.

Apart from `$('.submit-button').click(...)` you can use `$('#contactForm').submit( function() { /* code that's now in the click handler */ }. This would make the code a little more fail-safe, in case you might want to rename or remove that button, or if you want to manually submit the form from a piece of code. (Running`$('#contactForm').submit()` and passing no event handler actually triggers the submission of the form, this works for all other events too).

Hope this helps!