# How to perform validation on a form in javascript before going to other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have tried many ways but when submit button is clicked it directly moves to next page without validating in client side through javascript. Please provide me the solution to this problem.

Here is the code:

```js
 function teacherValidateForm(){
 var tuid=document.getElementById("tusername");
 var tnme=document.getElementById("tname");
 var tmail=document.getElementById("temail");
 var tpsd=document.getElementById("tpssswod");
 var tiname=document.getElementById("tiname");
 
 function validateTID(tuid){
  var message= "Username must start with a letter and must be of minimum 5 letters and '_' and '.' is allowed";
  if((!tuid.match(/^[[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9/._]*]{5,}$/)) || tuid.value==""){
   document.getElementById(uname).innerHTML=message;

   return false;
  }
  else return true;
 }
 function validateTName(){
  var message="Teacher's name muct not contain special characters and numbers";
  if((!tnme.match(/^[A-Za-z]*\s{1}[A-Za-z]*$/) || tnme.value==""){
    document.getElementById(name).innerHTML=message;

   return false;
  }else return true;
 }
 function validateTEmail(){
  var message="Enter a valid email";
  if((!tmail.match(/^[A-Za-z\._\-0-9]*[@][A-Za-z]*[\.][a-z]{2,4}*$/) || tmail.value==""){
    document.getElementById(email).innerHTML=message;

   return false;
  }else return true;
 }

 function validateTPass(){
  var message="Password must contain special cahacters, one catital letter atleast and must be mininum 8 letters";
  if((!tpsd.match(/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,}$/) || tpsd.value==""){
    document.getElementById(password).innerHTML=message;

   return false;
  }else return true;
 }
 function validateTName(){
  var message="Institute's name muct not contain special characters and numbers";
  if((!tiname.match(/^[A-Za-z]*\s{1}[A-Za-z]*$/) || tnme.value==""){
    document.getElementById(iname).innerHTML=message;

   return false;
  }else return true;
 }
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container-fluid" id="home">
<div class="text-center ">
 <p></p><br/><br/><br/><br/>
 
 <div class="container-fluid text-center">
  
    <h4  style="font-family:sans-serif; color: #000; size: 60px; font-weight: bold">Registration form</h4></div>
   
 </div>
<form name="teachersignup" class="form-horizontal" action="teacherLogin.jsp"  method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label  class="control-label col-md-4" style="color:#000; font-size:15px" >User Name: </label>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tusername"  />&nbsp; <span class="error" id="uname"></span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-md-4" style="color:#000; font-size:15px" >Teacher's Name: </label>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tname"  />&nbsp; <span class="error" id="name" ></span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="email" class="control-label col-md-4" style="color:#000; font-size:15px" >Email: </label>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="temail"  />&nbsp; <span class="error" id="email"></span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="pswd" class="control-label col-md-4" style="color:#000; font-size:15px" >Password: </label>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="tpassword"  />&nbsp;<span class="error" id="password"></span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="iname" class="control-label col-md-4" style="color:#000; font-size:15px" >Institute's Name: </label>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tiname"  />&nbsp;<span class="error" id="iname"></span>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onsubmit="teacherValidateForm();">Submit</button>
  </div>
 </form>
   
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this: [preventDefault()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp)

Comment: Please use this below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999210/how-do-i-call-a-jquery-function-on-submitting-a-form

Comment: @HarshilDave I have given the javascipt code too

Comment: @Razorphyn where to write the precentDefault() ?

Comment: @Razorphyn where to use preventDefault() ?

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors there. first you have to return value from the function in the html markup:

Comment: <form name="ff1" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">

Comment: i have used action for moving to the next jsp page

Answer (score 0):

Firstly use `<form name="teachersignup" class="form-horizontal" action="teacherLogin.jsp"  method="POST" onsubmit="return teacherValidateForm();>`

Then you can try the below function.Assuming that all your **regular expressions** are correct the below function should work just fine.

```
function teacherValidateForm()
        {
            var tuid=document.getElementById("tusername");
            var tnme=document.getElementById("tname");
            var tmail=document.getElementById("temail");
            var tpsd=document.getElementById("tpssswod");
            var tiname=document.getElementById("tiname");

            if(!tuid.match(/^[[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9/._]*]{5,}$/) || tuid.value=="")
            {
                var message= "Username must start with a letter and must be of minimum 5 letters and '_' and '.' is allowed";

                document.getElementById(uname).innerHTML=message;
                return false;
            }

            if(!tnme.match(/^[A-Za-z]*\s{1}[A-Za-z]*$/) || tnme.value=="")
            {
                var message="Teacher's name muct not contain special characters and numbers";
                document.getElementById(name).innerHTML=message;
                return false;
            }

            if(!tmail.match(/^[A-Za-z\._\-0-9]*[@][A-Za-z]*[\.][a-z]{2,4}*$/) || tmail.value=="")
            {
                var message="Enter a valid email";
                document.getElementById(email).innerHTML=message;
                return false;
            }

            if(!tpsd.match(/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,}$/) || tpsd.value=="")
            {
                var message="Password must contain special cahacters, one catital letter atleast and must be mininum 8 letters";
                document.getElementById(password).innerHTML=message;
                return false;
            }

            if(!tiname.match(/^[A-Za-z]*\s{1}[A-Za-z]*$/) || tnme.value=="")
            {
                var message="Institute's name muct not contain special characters and numbers";
                document.getElementById(iname).innerHTML=message;
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: It's still not working. It is directly moving to next page.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong.

```
        var tuid=document.getElementById("tusername");
        var tnme=document.getElementById("tname");
        var tmail=document.getElementById("temail");
        var tpsd=document.getElementById("tpssswod");
        var tiname=document.getElementById("tiname");
```

Actually you are assigning those variable with the HTML input elements, but you need the values. So made some changes in these codes

```
        var tuid=document.getElementById("tusername").value;
        var tnme=document.getElementById("tname").value;
        var tmail=document.getElementById("temail").value;
        var tpsd=document.getElementById("tpssswod").value;
        var tiname=document.getElementById("tiname").value;
```

Comment: Tell if you still have the problem.